# Any Open source Internationalization/localization framework for web application e.g. JSF, Struts, Spring MVC

Tags: jsf, localization

I have created a JSF application where in to implement localization, I need to create separate property files for each locale. Is there any way that these can be generated dynamically or any means of reducing the effort to minimum. Google translator is not a option for me.

Update:

User A have stored Data-A in Hindi language in database, Some User B comes in from french, now i want my application to show Data-A to user B in language French.

Comment: JSF actually provides a way to do that. However, your question is not totally clear, are you talking about the internationalization mechanism or the translation itself? 'Google translator is not a option for me' caused me to wonder.

Comment: please see section Update in question.

Comment: There are totally different things. Properties files define the static data to be shown in the app. However, what you want is to translate a current input (stored in the DB) from a user for other user. That's a more complicated thing. In my opinion you have two options, let the user A input the data in both languages or go through some translating service/library to translate it authomatically before you store it in the DB. That's obviously going to make your translation more neglected.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the best and optimized way.

Comment: If performance is a must, you can use a library instead of a WS api.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank buddy, That would be error prone, i would rather go for google api.

Comment: @NavdeepSingh *lol* Right--machine translations are better than humans. Except never.

Comment: @Anonymous can you please explain the reason for down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Check this blog - http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

MK Yong tries to explain what you might be looking for, with examples.

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but hope it helps.  Supporting muti locales are never easy.  You end up having multiple views that support each locale.

Comment: there we have to put *.properties file separately each and every time, I want some automated framework where in this work can be reduced to the minimum.Thanks

Comment: You can always automate creating locale specific configuration files from Java.  Write some sort of Java code to generate these files.  If you are looking to auto generate separate html and jsf files, you can look into generating such files from Java too.

Comment: where do i get the translated text in such case for some specific language entered.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that can translate text for you?  There's a free web service tool - http://www.webservicex.net/TranslateService.asmx?WSDL - You can also use translator APIs from Google translator or Microsoft API from here - http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis